# Selectindex change event is not firing using asp.net web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a searchable dropdown using javascript.when i search and select a value from the dropdown it is not firing the selectedindexchange event.i tried but i have not found a solution pls anyone help me to solve the issue.
js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
     (function ($) {
         $.widget("custom.combobox", {
             _create: function () {
                 this.wrapper = $("<span>")
          .addClass("custom-combobox")
          .insertAfter(this.element);

                 this.element.hide();
                 this._createAutocomplete();
                 this._createShowAllButton();
             },

             _createAutocomplete: function () {
                 var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

                 this.input = $("<input>")
          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
          .val(value)
          .attr("title", "")
          .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
          .autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 0,
              source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
          })
          .tooltip({
              tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

                 this._on(this.input, {
                     autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                         ui.item.option.selected = true;
                         this._trigger("select", event, {
                             item: ui.item.option
                         });
                     },

                     autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                 });
             },

             _createShowAllButton: function () {
                 var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

                 $("<a>")
          .attr("tabIndex", -1)
          .attr("title", "Show All Items")
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
          .button({
              icons: {
                  primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
              },
              text: false
          })
          .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
          .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
          .mousedown(function () {
              wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
          })
          .click(function () {
              input.focus();

              // Close if already visible
              if (wasOpen) {
                  return;
              }

              // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
              input.autocomplete("search", "");
          });
             },

             _source: function (request, response) {
                 var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                 response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                     var text = $(this).text();
                     if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                         return {
                             label: text,
                             value: text,
                             option: this
                         };
                 }));
             },

             _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

                 // Selected an item, nothing to do
                 if (ui.item) {
                     return;
                 }

                 // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                 var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
                 this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                     if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                         this.selected = valid = true;
                         return false;
                     }
                 });

                 // Found a match, nothing to do
                 if (valid) {
                     return;
                 }

                 // Remove invalid value
                 this.input
          .val("")
          .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
          .tooltip("open");
                 this.element.val("");
                 this._delay(function () {
                     this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                 }, 2500);
                 this.input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
             },

             _destroy: function () {
                 this.wrapper.remove();
                 this.element.show();
             }
         });
     })(jQuery);
     $(function () {
         $(".cbAutoList1").combobox();
         $("#toggle").click(function () {
             $(".cbAutoList1").toggle();
         });
     });
</script>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="cbAutoList" runat="server" CssClass="cbAutoList1" AutoPostBack="true"  EnableViewState="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbAutoList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
       <asp:ListItem Value="hai1" >hai1</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="hello2" >hello2</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>
```

codebehind

```
public delegate void LeavingFocusHandler(int CurrentIndex);

        public event LeavingFocusHandler LeavingFocus;
 public string strValue { get; set; } 
        public int ItemIndex { get; set; }
 protected void cbAutoList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cbAutoList.Items.Count > 0)
                    this.strValue = cbAutoList.Items[cbAutoList.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                else
                    this.strValue = string.Empty;

                if (this.LeavingFocus != null)
                {
                    this.LeavingFocus(this.ItemIndex);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the value selected in the DropDownList you can just use `SelectedValue`:

```
this.strValue = cbAutoList.SelectedValue;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx

Comment: when i debug it is not moving to cbAutoList_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Is your DDList within an UpdatePanel?